# How to replace "* * *" with NA in r?

Tags: r, replace

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```r
> str(CORUCHE3_new)

'data.frame':   313920 obs. of  10 variables:        
 $ N    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...        
 $ Date : chr  "2015-07-27 00:00:00" "2015-07-27 00:05:00" "2015-07-27 00:10:00" "2015-07-27 00:15:00" ...        
 $ UI630: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UI800: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UR630: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UR800: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UI532: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UI570: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UR532: chr  NA NA NA NA ...        
 $ UR570: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

In the columns UR630 UR800 UR532 UR570 some rows were automatically filled with "* * *"by the datalogger. I've been trying to replace the "***"with NA but without success.

How can I replace this "* * *" by NA?

These are some of the codes that I've been using:

```r
CORUCHE3_new[CORUCHE3_new == "* * *"] <- NA        
CORUCHE3_new <- replace(CORUCHE3_new, CORUCHE3_new == "* * *", NA)          
CORUCHE3_new<-CORUCHE3_new %>% replace("* * *", NA)      
CORUCHE3_new$UR570 <- replace(CORUCHE3_new$UR570, CORUCHE3_new$UR570 == '* * *', NA)
```

For instance, I would also try to find a code where I would replace all "***" independently of the column.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share reproducible example. Does the below code work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('UR'), ~ case_when(. == '* * *' ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ .)))
  N UR630 UR800
1 1     A     D
2 2     B     F
3 3     C  <NA>
4 4  <NA>     G
```

Sample data used:

```
df
  N UR630 UR800
1 1     A     D
2 2     B     F
3 3     C * * *
4 4 * * *     G
```